# If $(x_n)$ is an unbounded increasing sequence then $\sum (1-x_n/x_{n+1})$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Let {$x_n$} be monotone increasing sequence of positive real numbers. Show that if {$x_n$} is unbounded, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}})$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Using the well-known inequality $\ln a\leq a-1$ with $a=x_{k+1}/x_k$ we obtain
$$
\ln x_{k+1}-\ln x_k\leq \frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{x_k}
$$
Adding these inequalities for $k\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$, we obtain
$$
\ln x_{n}-\ln x_1\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{x_k}
$$
but the sequence $\{x_n\}$ in increasing and unbounded, hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{x_k}=+\infty.\tag{1}
$$
Now  suppose, for contradiction, that the  considered series does converge, $i.e.$
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{x_{k+1}}<+\infty\tag{2}$$
 then its general term must tend to zero,
that is $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{x_k}{x_{n+1}}=1$, which implies that
$$
\dfrac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{x_{k+1}}\sim_{\infty}\dfrac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{x_{k}}
$$
and contradicts (1). This contradiction proves that (2) is absurd and the series
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{x_{k+1}}$  must be divergent.

Comment: Same thing here. I dun understand why we can use approximation to compute limit

Comment: @user136266 your are not computing anything, you are proving the series diverges and approximation is a legit way of doing it. but if you don't like it you can try this approach http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746257/prove-sum-infty-n-1-fraca-n-a-n-1a-n-infty

Answer (score 2):

If $\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}$ does not tend to $1$ then the sequence diverges because the $n$th term does not tend to zero.  If $\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}\to 1$ then your sequence is equivalent to the sequence $\log(\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}})$ which diverges by a telescoping series argument.  The reason the sequence is equivalent to $\log(\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}})$ is because as $x\to 0$ one has $\log (1+x)\sim x$.

Comment: I don't get how is the sequence equivalent to $log(x_n/x_{n+1})$. Where does boundedness come into play here?

Comment: why we can use approximation when finding limit? I mean i haven't learnt such a thing yet? Is it rigorous to do that?

Comment: Yes, if we have to positive sequences which are equivalent (more generally, differ by at most a certain fixed constant), then they will converge or diverge simultaneously.  This is obvious because the constants provide a way of bounding each sequence in terms of the other.

Comment: doesn't that mean that we have to find the fixed constant first to make the proof rigorous?

Comment: If $x\to 0$ then $\frac{\log (x+1)}{x}\to 1$ and therefore for $x$ sufficiently close to $0$ the ratio will be between 1/2 and 2.