# Prove $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{a_{n}-a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Prove $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{a_{n}-a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}=\infty$$
Where $a_{n}$ is an increasing sequence of positive terms that goes to infinity.

I tried to approach it with $\log(a_{n})$ like a classical version of this problem but i could not show that the difference with respect to the logarithm is finite.
Any help or hint will be appreciated

Comment: Consider that $a_n=n$ yields the harmonic series.  You might try to reproduce an argument for that series with this one.

Comment: @Thomas.Are u saying prove that it s not cauchy?

Comment: No, that wasn't what I was saying. There is a standard proof that $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$ diverges. This theorem uses the same essential proof.

Comment: @clark not the same one. This one is different

Comment: @user114032 strictly speaking but you can apply both arguments with a little to none adjustments.

Answer (score 3):

Show that:

$$\sum_{n=N+1}^M \frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{a_n} \geq \frac{a_M-a_N}{a_M}$$

Then pick an increasing sequence $N_i$ so that $a_{N_{i+1}}\geq 2A_{N_i}$.

Then $$\sum_{n=N_i+1}^{N_{i+1}}\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{a_n}\geq 1$$

Use this to deduce the series diverges.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot. Do you know if this can be compared to the log of an by any means.

Comment: It is definitely a lower Reimann sum for $\int_{a_0}^{a_N}\frac{dt}{t}$, so the sums are bounded above by $\log(a_N/a_0)$. But I think it can diverge much more slowly...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews why I can pick an increasing sequence $N_i$ so that $a_{N_{i+1}} \geq 2A_{N_i}$?