# Find a very slow growing function

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I'm trying to find a continuous increasing function $f$ in $[1,\infty)$ such that

$1-\frac{f(x)}{f(2x)} = O(1/\log^c(x))$ for some constant $c>1$, and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$.

Note if $c=1$, $f(x)=\log(x)$ works well, when as soon as $c>1$, I can't come up with any nice function that works. It seems iterating log $k$ times is not enough.

Comment: The inverse of the [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse) is known to be an extremely slowly growing function.

Comment: It's not continuous, but sure I can do linear interpolations.  But I don't see how to prove that inverse Ackermann function must satisfy the condition.

Comment: @CareBear yes, I just edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried the cth root of log(x)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interestingly, such function doesn't exist. The point is, that
$$
\sum_{n= 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^c}
$$
converges for $c > 1$. Assuming otherwise, condition implies existence of constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$, such that for any $x$,
$$
1-\frac{f(x)}{f(2x)} < \frac{C}{\log^{c}(x)}
$$
Now apply this for numbers $b_n = 2^{n}$ to get
$$
1-\frac{f(2^n)}{f(2^{n+1})} < \frac{C}{\log^{c}(2^{n})} = \frac{C}{n^c\log^{c}(2)}.
$$
Now, summing this inequality for all positive integers ($f(b_n) = a_{n})$, we get
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\right) < \frac{C}{\log^{c}(2)}\sum_{n= 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^c} < \infty,
$$
but since as $n \to \infty$, $2^{n} \to \infty $ and so $a_{n} = f(2^{n}) \to \infty $, according to [Prove $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{a_{n}-a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}=\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746257/prove-sum-infty-n-1-fraca-n-a-n-1a-n-infty?lq=1) left-hand side diverges, a contradiction.