# Help in understanding the solution to proving $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{a_{n}-a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{a_{n}-a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}=\infty$$
Where $a_{n}$ is an increasing sequence of positive terms that goes to infinity.

[Prove $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{a_{n}-a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}=\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746257/prove-sum-infty-n-1-fraca-n-a-n-1a-n-infty/746265#comment2533558_746265)

In the solution given, it picks an increasing sequence $N_i$ so that $a_{N_{i+1}} > 2 A_{N_{i+1}}$. Why we can do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be $a_{N_{i+1}}>2a_{N_i}$, instead of the upper case one.

That is because $a_i$ is going to infinity, so we can find $a_i$s arbitrarily large, larger than $2a_{N_i}$, and we set that $i$ to be $N_{i+1}$.